# JQuery DataPicker add on the

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put datepicker on my Application . Can you guys please help me?. I don't have much knowledge on JQuery . Do I need add any Extra Plugin for that or Just type put only the coding??.This is the coding I using for that.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <%@include file="header.jsp"%>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#example6').datetimepicker({
    showSecond: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
    stepHour: 2,
    stepMinute: 10,
    stepSecond: 10
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <div id="templatemo_content_right">
     <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <center>
            <form action="LoginServlet" method="POST" id="theform" name="theform">
                <table cellspacing="20" cellpading="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Department Id:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="departmentId" id="userName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Department Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="departmentName" id="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Department Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="departmentName" id="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Appointed Date:</td>
                        <td><input id="example6" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>



            </form>
        </center>

        <div class="cleaner_with_height">&nbsp;</div>

    </div> <!-- end of content right -->
    <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jQuery UI script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Add it right after the jQuery script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Between the load of jQuery and your script, you need to load the plugin. Or I missed something. Also, for future reference, if you get stuck, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)